# FFMPEG distorting when resampling audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, flac

I'm making an mp3 from a flac file with ffmpeg. This is usually hum-dum for me.

Tonight, for some reason, the converted audio is distorting when I use the same commands I've always used. After troubleshooting, it appears the problem is the "-out_sample_rate" flag.

My command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -write_id3v1 1 -id3v2_version 3 -dither_method modified_e_weighted -out_sample_rate 44.1k -b:a 320k output.mp3
```

The audio in the mp3 is then incredibly distorted by a jacked gain resulting in digital clipping.

I've tried updating ffmpeg, and then problem remains. I've tried converting various sample rates (44.1k source files, 48k source files, 96k source files) to both 44.1k and 48k mp3s, problem remains whenever there's a conversion.

I'm on macOS, and I installed  ffmpeg via homebrew.

Any ideas?

Comment: changing "-out_sample_rate 44.1k" to "-ar 44100" has the same result.

Comment: Share the full log. Have you tested a file which earlier converted fine with this command?

Comment: Do your "old" files still work? If so then I'd submit a sample to the ffmpeg trac as "this is broken"...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the distortion comes from resampling?

Even the poorest resampling algorithm doesn't distort. More typical artifacts from poor resampling are harsh high frequencies due to aliasing and quantisation noise.

FFmpeg's resampler isn't the very best but it isn't bad at all. It shouldn't lead to distortion at all. Enough for average use.

How much headroom does the source file have?

If not enough, the resampling or the MP3 conversion may lead to clipping. The MP3 encoder removes frequencies from the signal (even at 320kbps) so the waveform will alter.

So reimport the encoded MP3 into an audio editor and look for clipping.

If not sure, which step the distortion comes from, split the command up and look, which step leads to clipping:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -write_id3v1 1 -id3v2_version 3 -dither_method modified_e_weighted -out_sample_rate 44.1k intermediate.flac

ffmpeg -i intermediate.flac -b:a 320k output.mp3
```

There should be a headroom of at least 1dB left before it gets converted to MP3. If not, lower the gain before.

If the resampling of the intermediate.flac leads to a significant gain in amplitude, the original input.flac is poorly mastered. If so (and the quality is really important), do the SR conversion in an audio editor (i.e. Audacity, it does a better resampling job than FFMpeg) and apply a limiter between the resampling and dithering step to lower the few strong peaks nicely.

If that doesn't help: What exactly does input.flac contain? Music? Noise? Speech? and is it selfmade or taken from something else?

Comment: To confirm, the digital clipping is/was from an increased amplitude.

I went through the troubleshooting of splitting the command up before I posted the question, which is how I was able to bring it down to the resampler. At the time, it appeared it was the -out_sample_rate flag that was causing the problems. Doing it again, it appears it's the dither_method, with only triangular and rectangular working (meaning, not doing the increased gain). Of course, this is again the resampler. List of dither methods: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html